# usage example for chokidar in Meteor to prevent Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber

Tags: meteor

The code below gives me the Error: 'Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.'

```
import chokidar from 'chokidar';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
const Plates = new Mongo.Collection('plates');

var path = '~/Documents/dev/lpr/test';
var watcher = chokidar.watch(path, {
    ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
    persistent: true
});
watcher.on('add', path => {
    console.log(`DEBUG: File ${path} has been added`);
    Plates.insert({
        path,
    })
});
```

The Meteor documentation (https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#wrap-async) suggests using Meteor.wrapAsync to solve this issue but I don't understand how to apply in this case?

e.g. below returns 'TypeError: watcherFiber.on is not a function'

```
var watcherFiber = Meteor.wrapAsync(chokidar.watch(path, {
    ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
    persistent: true
}));

watcherFiber
    .on('add', path => {
        console.log(`DEBUG: File ${path} has been added`);
        Plates.insert({
            path,
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error text points you to the correct way to do that.

It should be like this:

```
watcher.on('add', Meteor.bindEnvironment(path => {
    console.log(`DEBUG: File ${path} has been added`);
    Plates.insert({
        path,
    });
}));
```